# add CSS styles to Style object asp net

Tags: asp.net, css, styles, custom-controls

I am working with [Style] class in this way:

```
public class ServerControl1 : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    ....

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
      Style wrapperStyle = new Style();

      wrapperStyle.BorderColor = BorderColor;
      ....
      ....

      this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(wrapperStyle, null, key);

      .....
     }
}
```

How can I add such things as [line-height] or other?

Comment: why don't you simply give the control a css class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wrapperStyle.Attributes.Add("class","wrapper_class");
```

In your CSS file

```
.wrapper_class {
    line-height:24px;
}
```

Edited:

```
wrapperStyle.Style.Add("line-height","24px");
```

Comment: My approach is to make all css in one place (like Style class) and add it to header.I want to make independent control and not make manual css on aspx or css-files.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to do that, the overhead from adding another class and loading the CSS like that would have to be higher than adding an external CSS file...

Comment: I want every user can use my component without any custom working with css [he can set avaible properties to my component].

Comment: Edited answer to include code for adding individual styles. I still think it's too much overhead. Including a CSS sheet that the user could edit makes more sense.

Comment: pretty,but I cant find {Style} property in Style class

Comment: It's not part of the style class.